# Is it possible to display a div on hover of a <p> tag

Tags: html, css, web

I've styled a `<p>` tag which behaves as a cart button.

Now I want to make a pop up box which will appear on hover of the `<p>` tag containing cart details in it.

Comment: It's definitely possible. If you want a CSS solution, it would depend on the structure of your markup, though. Please provide relevant HTML/CSS.

Comment: http://jsbin.com/cijok/1/edit is a simple example of what you might want to do. Your surrounding markup is however crucial to know so we can say anything at all.

Comment: yes there are many ways to do it

Comment: #div.product:hover > p.cart_details{display:block;}

Answer (score 2):

HTML

```
   <div id="product_list">
   <p class="poverlay" style="display:none;">Cart Details</p>      
    test elements test elements test elements test elements test elements
   </div>
```

CSS

```
    <style>
    #product_list{
     display:block;
     z-index:1;
     width:100px;
     height:100px;
     border:1px solid #ccc;
     padding:10px;
    }
    #product_list:hover > p.poverlay {
        display:block !important;
        top:0px;
        left:0px;
        position:absolute;
        padding:10px;
        color:#f00;
        font-weight:bold;
        z-index:2;
    }
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in your CSS:

Your pop up starts hidden:

```
#popupId{
    display: none;
}
```

You make it appear when you hover your `p` element

```
p:hover #popupId{
    display: block;
}
```

And you fill it with the information you want to show.

Answer (score 0):

yeh I did it !!!! in the way I want.

Thanks all Josh ,Ankit, thriqon , punitha